# Can't run Python visual element in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm trying to create a hist plot in Power BI.
I got installed ANaconda, MS Vusial Code.
Screenshots with my settings:
[image: Power BI setting]
[image: Python home folder]
I'm trying make hist with simple table with 1 column.

The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script:

```py
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(reg_min_ses_dt)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.histplot(data=dataset['reg_min_ses_dt'])

plt.show()
```

But I get this error:
[image: Error text 1]
[image: Error text 2]

I think, I just didn't set up some python extension or something else.

I just want make Python visual like this.
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **activate conda** before you can use its packages in PBIDesktop.exe. Simple as that.